# Trying to access Twitter returns Cannot import data as JSON

Tags: social-media

I am trying to use the Social features of Mathematica 10. The Facebook interaction works, but with Twitter I am getting "Cannot import data as JSON".

Example:

```
In[16]:= ServiceExecute["Twitter", "LastTweet", {"ScreenName" -> 
   "stephen_wolfram"}]

During evaluation of In[16]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>

Out[16]= ServiceExecute["Twitter", "LastTweet", {"ScreenName" -> 
   "stephen_wolfram"}]
```

I have tried `ClearSystemCache[]` but this has no impact. I am getting the valid token from Twitter and it is marked as an allowed App with read access.

If I use `SocialMediaData[]` it fails but returns numbers. Example:

```
In[17]:= SocialMediaData["Twitter", "Followers"] // Short
```

Generates this: 
[image: output showing numbers]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or how to diagnose/solve this?

**[Edit]**

Further testing.

Restarting the client then `ServiceExecute[]` works. However `SocialMediaData[]` doesn't. Restarting the client and running `SocialMediaData[]` first fails but displays some names. Eg.

[image]

Also I've noticed that ServiceExecute allows you to save your Auth key, but SocialMediaData doesn't.

Comment: It works for me. It might be something temporary for you, so try restarting MMA etc.

Comment: Actually that fixes ServiceExecute, but SocialMediaData is still broken. :(

Comment: Maybe send a message as "product feedback" [here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) and see what they have to say about intermittent problems. Perhaps there is an explanation you can report back.

Comment: Done. Will see what they say. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the temporary answer at this time.

I got a response from support and they have reproduced the issue and reported it to development. So it is under investigation.

---

Update: 14th Sept 2015. I've tested this on Mathematica 10.2 and it appears to work for the first option. You get a popup to authenticate with Twitter. You can have it remember connection.

For the other calls, it still seems to fail.

Comment: Do you have any update for us? :)

Comment: @VividD Forgot all about this. Updated answer.